# How to create views in Mongoose or how to get using native driver access

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Looks like mongoose does not support views - as far as I have searched. So, I tried using native MongoDB commands like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
...
mongoose.connection.db.createView("<view name>", "<source collection>", [
 {
    $lookup: { ... }
 },
 {  
    $project: { ... }
 },
 { $unwind: ... }
])
```

But I get this error:

```
mongoose.connection.db.createView("<view name>", "<source coll.>", [

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createView')
```

Update: if I make sure I wait till "db" connection is setup, then `db` is defined but still I get:

```
TypeError: mongoose.connection.db.createView is not a function
```

Using mongoose version 6.8.1. What am I missing? I need to join two collections and create a view.

Comment: '_I need to join two collections_' is different than '_I need to create a view _'. You can join two collections without creating a view. Is there any particular reason that the app can't run the aggregation directly or that it must be what creates the view (instead of, for example, doing it in the shell)?